# Crystal report If condition not show the decimal places

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm try to use If condition in CrystalReport formula field. Actual value is 86.40. But Report shows 86.00
Please help me.

This is formula field condion

```
if {Invoice_Report;1.TaxTyp} = "VAT" then
 ({Invoice_Report;1.TaxAmt})
else if {Invoice_Report;1.TaxTyp} = "SVAT" then
 ({Invoice_Report;1.TaxAmt})
```

I also tried to use ToText(---------,"00.00") this one also not work..
Thanks..

Comment: Why are you using an `IF` statement?  The results are the same in both cases.

Comment: Are you *certain* that the data is 86.40?  Specifically, how are you confirming this?

Comment: have you updated datatype of that field. for example when you have created that table with int datatype then you have changed it to decimal. so, you have to Verify Report first.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
totext({Invoice_Report;1.TaxAmt},2)
```